# How can I read different .txt files in R but not join them in the same data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to read many `.txt` files into dataframes from one folder. The `.txt` file names are of the form `angles_*_dat.result` (e.g. `angles_1_dat.result`, `angles_2_dat.result`).

I am using this but this look "newbie" :

```
data1 <- read.table("~/data/angles_medias_1.dat.results.dat.", quote="\"", comment.char="")
data2 <- read.table("~/data/angles_medias_2.dat.results.dat.", quote="\"", comment.char="")
data3 <- read.table("~/data/angles_medias_3.dat.results.dat.", quote="\"", comment.char="")
data4 <- read.table("~/data/angles_medias_4.dat.results.dat.", quote="\"", comment.char="")
data5 <- read.table("~/data/angles_medias_5.dat.results.dat.", quote="\"", comment.char="")
data6 <- read.table("~/data/angles_medias_6.dat.results.dat", quote="\"", comment.char="")
data7 <- read.table("~/data/angles_medias_7.dat.results.dat", quote="\"", comment.char="")
data8 <- read.table("~/data/angles_medias_8.dat.results.dat", quote="\"", comment.char="")
data9 <- read.table("~/data/angles_medias_9.dat.results.dat", quote="\"", comment.char="")
data10 <- read.table("~/data/angles_medias_10.dat.results.dat", quote="\"", comment.char="")
```

Is there any other way (eg. Loop) to load all the data files in different dataframe?

EDIT:

E.g data:

```
V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7   V8  V9  
100 0   100 100 0   100 100 100 100  
100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 
100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 
100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 
100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
files_to_read <- dir(pattern = ".txt") # make sure only the files you want to read are in this dir

n <- 0
for(i in 1:length(files_to_read)){
  assign(paste("df",n,sep=""), read.table(files_to_read[i], quote="\"", comment.char=""))
  n <- n+1
}
```

If there are `.txt` files you don't want to import in that directory you can either create a new directory with only the `.txt` files you want to import or further customize the `pattern` to only match the files you want to import.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. R shows me this error: error in file(file rt ) cannot open the connection

Comment: Set your working directory to the folder where the `.txt` files are located

Answer (score 3):

You can read them all into a list. That's arguably cleaner than hacking the global namespace.

```
files <- dir(directory, pattern = ".txt")  # directory is the path to the directory containing the files
dframes <- lapply(files, read.table, quote="\"", comment.char="")
```

You can then acces the dataframes in the list, e.g. `dframes[[1]]` for the first df. If you prefer the `$` access syntax:

```
names(dframes) <- sapply(as.character(1:length(files)), function(i) paste("df", i, sep=""))
```

Now you can access the same dataframe as `dframes$df1`

Answer (score 3):

Using `lapply`:

```
allTextFiles <- list.files(pattern = ".txt")

alldfs <- lapply(allTextFiles, function(x) { 
          textfiles <- read.table(x, quote="\"", comment.char="")
          })

alldfs <- lapply(x = alldfs, seq_along(alldfs), function(x, i) {
          assign(paste0("data", i), x[[i]], envir=.GlobalEnv)
          })
```